# MATLAB GUIDE button must be pressed twice?

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I'm making a GUI with guide. I have a push button the user clicks and the callback is as folows : (what matters are the tirst two lines  really...

```
   function SetParticleRoiSize_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to SetParticleRoiSize (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
handles=guidata(hObject);
particleroiSize=imrect;% - draw a rectagle around the particle to get a meausr eof ROI size
roiPoints=getPosition(particleroiSize); %-get tha parameters fo the rectanlge
partX1 = round(roiPoints(1));
partY1 = round(roiPoints(2));
partX2 = round(partX1 + roiPoints(3));
partY2 = round(partY1 + roiPoints(4)); % these are the ROi positions in pixels

roiHeight = round(roiPoints(3)); % - these are just the ROI width and height
roiWidth  = round(roiPoints(4));

handles=guidata(hObject); %_ update all the handles...
handles.partX1=partX1;
handles.partX2=partX2;
handles.partY1=partY1;
handles.partY2=partY2;

handles.roicenterX = (partX1 + round(roiPoints(3))/2);
handles.roicenterY= (partY1 + round(roiPoints(4))/2);

handles.roiHeight = roiHeight;
handles.roiWidth = roiWidth;

current_slice = round(get(handles.Image_Slider,'Value'));
handles.current_slice=current_slice;
particleImage=handles.Image_Sequence_Data(partY1:partY2,partX1:partX2,current_slice);
handles.particleImage=particleImage;

set(handles.RoiSizeDisplay,'String',['Particle ROI is ',' ',num2str(roiHeight),' ', ' by ',num2str(roiWidth)] );

guidata(hObject,handles);  %- at this point we now have the particle in the roi and the size of the roi stored.
```

The issue I am  having is that when the user clicks the button the first time, nothing happens (i.e. the imrect line seems to not get called at all). When the user clicks the button again then they can draw a rectangle on the image but my program throws out an error

```
Error in imrect (line 83)
            [h_group,draw_api] = imrectAPI(varargin{:});

Error in SemiAutomated_Fionv2p2_5>SetParticleRoiSize_Callback (line 291)
particleroiSize=imrect;% - draw a rectagle around the particle to get a meausr eof ROI size

Error in gui_mainfcn (line 96)
        feval(varargin{:});

Error in SemiAutomated_Fionv2p2_5 (line 56)
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});

Error in
@(hObject,eventdata)SemiAutomated_Fionv2p2_5('SetParticleRoiSize_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))


Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback
```

I guess the error is because there is no imrect created on the first button click. 
Can someone please explain to me why this button needs to be clicked twice to work? (and even then it still gives an error...)

thanks...
-j

Comment: Use a [breakpoint](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html#brqxeeu-182) to see if the callback is being executed.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this call:

`handles=guidata(hObject); %_ update all the handles...`

is incorrectly used; you might need to replace it with `guidata(hObject,handles)` in order to actually update the handles structure. Moreover, since you already call `guidata(hObject,handles)` at the end of the callback you can delete this line altogether I think.

As it's currently implemented, you:

1) get the handles structure with `handles = guidata(hObject);`

2) store information in it

```
    particleroiSize=imrect;% - draw a rectagle around the particle to get a meausr eof ROI size
    roiPoints=getPosition(particleroiSize); %-get tha parameters fo the rectanlge
    partX1 = round(roiPoints(1));
    partY1 = round(roiPoints(2));
    partX2 = round(partX1 + roiPoints(3));
    partY2 = round(partY1 + roiPoints(4)); % these are the ROi positions in pixels

roiHeight = round(roiPoints(3)); % - these are just the ROI width and height
roiWidth  = round(roiPoints(4));
```

3) then call it again (`handles = guidata(hObject)`)`.

Hence on your second call to retrieve the data you have not previously updated it, so I guess Matlab does not like it.

It might not be the specific cause of your error but I think it's worth checking.

Comment: thanks for the advice but this has not solved the problem. someone suggested to me it might be related to java so when i do a version -java I get Java 1.6.0_65-b14-462-11M4609 with Apple Inc. Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode

Answer (score 0):

I had 3 different axes in my figure. The first version of the program only had 1 axes so it worked fine. After adding the other axes to the GUI (via GUIDE) when I ran just imrect.. I think it was not choosing the axes I wanted..I added a parent handles.correct axes and now it works perfectly!